# Cordova/Phonegap : InApp browser disable options

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am new to hybrid mobile app development, I am learning cordova currently.

I am trying to open a external url from app; which it does. However, I want the target to open without navigation options that comes within the external website(like sliding opens next article).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the options you want to. For disabling the locationbar it would be:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

All options for Android and iOS can be found here -> [Cordova InAppBrowser Options](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen)

As far as i know there is no options which directly deactivates or disallows the "next" and "back" buttons inside the InAppBrowser-Bar with the "Done" button.

Comment: Thanks for your reply so quickly..location=no, just disables location bar;

Comment: What exactly do you want to disable. Like i said you'er not able to disable the for and back Button afaik